# WCF DateTime to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, wcf, nsdate

I am using a web services which returns a JSON WCF DateTime.

The string goes like `\/Date(1316397792913+0800)\/`

I am interested in extracting out the `1316397792` which is the time since 1st Jan 1970 in seconds. So that I can use the `NSDate timeIntervalSince1970` method to get the present time. I cropped out the last 3 digits as it's in milliseconds and the `timeIntervalSince1970` takes in seconds.

Here's what I am currently doing which does not work for dates somewhere before 2001 which has a time interval in ms since 1970 less than 10 characters.

```
NSString *dateString = @"\/Date(1316397792913+0800)\/";
    NSLog(@"dateString :%@", dateString);

    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:
                    [[dateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 10)] intValue]];
    NSLog(@"NSDate:%@", date);

dateString :/Date(1316397792913+0800)/
NSDate:2011-09-19 02:03:12 +0000
```

Therefore, I need a better work around playing with the dateString which does not assume everytime we will be feteching 10 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply get the substring between the index of `(` and the index of `+`. Something like:

```
NSRange begin = [dateString rangeOfString:"("];
NSRange end = [dateString rangeOfString:"+"];
NSString* milliSecondsSince1970 = [dateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(begin.location + 1, end.location - begin.location - 1)];
```

P.S: Check for the one off error.

Comment: NSRange begin = [dateString rangeOfString:@"("]; will return the range where it detects "(", not after it. How do I make it to detect a interger value instead?

Comment: Don't make it detect the integer value. As the integer begins after '(', add 1 to its index. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yup, I saw this easy way out. Thank you!

Comment: Just to point out it should be `NSString* secondsSince1970 = [dateString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(begin.location + 1, end.location - begin.location - 4)];` We need to trim off the last 3 digits as it's in milliseconds.

Comment: But end points to the '+', & not ')'. The milliseconds digits are after the +.

Comment: `1316397792913` is the milliseconds. `+0800` is the timezone